# Инверсия промежутка в массиве

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

На досуге познаю Pascal, и делаю разные манипуляции с массивами. Итак, в голову пришла идея сделать инверсию элементов (ОТ и ДО (элементы выбираются с клавиатуры)), делаю это все через процедуру

Например, имеется массив

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Задача в том, чтобы юзер выбрал два элемента, и этом промежутке произошла инверсия, например:
Ввод с клавиатуры элемент 5  и элемент 9, в итоге должно получиться, так:

```
1 2 3 4 9 8 7 6 5 10
```

Пытался делать так, но не понимаю, почему-то не получается, что-то я упускаю

```
const
  N = 100;

var
  count: integer;
  A: array[1..N] of integer;

procedure arrayReverse(p, s: integer); 
    var i, x: integer;
    begin
        if p < s then 
            for i := low(A) to count do
            begin
                x := a[p];
                A[p] := A[s];
                A[s] := x;
            end;
    end;

begin
    var p, s: integer;
      write('Кол-во элементов в массиве: '); 
      readln(count);

      for var i := 1 to count do
          A[i] := i; 

      write('Введите 1: '); read(p);
      write('Введите 2: '); read(s);

      arrayReverse(p, s);

      for var i := low(A) to count do write(A[i], ' ');
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       for i := 0 to (s - p) div 2 do
        begin
            x := A[p + i];
            A[p + i] := A[s - i];
            A[s - i] := x;
        end;
```

Comment: спасибо, а можно вопрос, зачем здесь использовать div 2?

Comment: @Scaralis'a в цикле надо пройти только половину диапазона, ограниченного индексами `p` и `s`

Comment: @Scaralis'a если убрать `div 2`, то массив не изменится, так как каждая пара элементов будет поменена местами дважды

Comment: еще раз благодарю

Comment: @Scaralis'a Пожалуйста. Успехов!